# Winforms application menu and application UI

Tags: winforms, menu

I am working on a little WinForm app and have been trying to find the answers to a few questions i have without any luck. Im a ASP.NET developer so WinForms development is new to me.

Here is my main question:

How do I create a menu system that once selected the contents will render in the Main form of the selected item. If its a GridView I want to the GridView to render inside the main application so they can navigate away without having to deal with the modal popup. I do not want to popup forms unless i explicitly say so. I guess the equivalent to this would be using a Master page in ASP.NET.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to Master pages in winforms would be MDI (multiple document interface), which is a hideous Windows 3.1-era abortion of a user interface.  Why this option is even still around, and why anyone still uses it, is beyond me.

The second closest thing (and something more acceptable as a UI) is just to have one main form in your application, and implement the different pieces of functionality your app requires as separate user controls which are displayed on the form and hidden as the context requires.

A weirder method, but one that might also work for you, is to use forms inheritance - design one "master" form with the menus and controls that you want to always be present, and then have each form in your app inherit from that master form.  This would not appear to the user to be much different from my second option above, so I wouldn't bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything similar to Master pages in WinForms.

The closest to what you want to use would be a TabControl selecting a different tab will display that tab over the other tabs. If you don't like the tab look you could extend the TabControl to not show the tabs or hack it together by placing the TabControl inside a panel just large enough to show the content but not the Tabs and change tabs programatically in your menu control.

Comment: MDI is similar to master pages (although MDI sucks, to be fair).